# Is it possible to programatically access the call hierarchy in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extensibility

Visual studio 2010 has added a call hierarchy function. Does anyone know if it is possible to access this from within a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a reference to \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CallHierarchy.Package.Definitions.dll and importing the ICallHierarchy service.

ICallHierarchy allows you to:

```
public interface ICallHierarchy
{
    void AddRootItem(ICallHierarchyMemberItem item);
    void ShowToolWindow();
}
```

You might also need other Call Hierarchy .dlls:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.CallHierarchy.Package.Implementation.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.CallHierarchy.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.CallHierarchy.Implementation.dll

Comment: This seems pretty close as I can see the interface definitions I need in the Language.CallHierarchy dll. However if I try to add the implementation dll as a reference it won't add it to the project. How do I get create some concrete objects in order to actually do some work?

Comment: You can implement ICallHierarchyMemberItem yourself, create your own object and add it to the Call Hierarchy toolwindow as a root. From there, WPF will use databinding to display your object in the tree. It can have children, Name, etc.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't quite what I wanted - I probably didn't specify it enough in the question, but I was hoping to be able to get Visual Studio to do the parsing of the code hierarchy and return the list for me